# Uninstall NVidia drivers?

Tags: upgrade, xorg, nvidia, apt, uninstall

I've upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 (in order to be able to upgrade to 11.04).

It seems like the current graphics drivers are incompatible with the latest kernel I have.
I don't know if I have installed drivers only from apt or if I have downloaded. I think it's only apt thou.

How do I uninstall all Nvidia drivers and revert to the default drivers? I've used at least 2 different multi monitor setup utilities, but it was last year so I don't remember much.

What config files do I need to change so that the default drivers works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try renaming the xorg.conf file and reboot:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

To remove the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-settings nvidia-current
```