# reset video driver to original ubuntu driver

Tags: 11.10

I have an nVidia and I installed the latest drivers from the nVidia web site. I then forgot to uninstall the driver before taking tons of updates and ended with an unbootable Ubuntu installation. Following directions from [this page](http://www.tuxation.com/chrooting-into-a-linux-environment.html) I managed to mount and get into the broken Ubuntu installation using the Ubuntu 11.10 LiveCD. Now the question is how can I remove the nVidia driver and reset it to the original Ubuntu installation via this Chrooting access?

For example, if I run the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42310/uninstall-nvidia-drivers) it won't work because the commands apply to the host running Ubuntu which is the one from the LiveCD and not the one I need to repair.

Comment: Unbootable, or just no GUI?  Can you get to a virtual terminal, by pressing Alt+F1, Alt+F2, etc (or possibly Ctrl+Alt+F1, etc)?  If you can get a command prompt that way, you can enter the commands required to repair.

Comment: You might even try to get into root mode by holding SHIFT just before Ubuntu starts booting. You can open (I believe it's called) recovery mode. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode (and note that you need SHIFT). As @Marty states, recovering from your actual system will be a lot easier than from a live disk.

Oh and consider changing the title of your question to include something like "from a Live boot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the details on [this](http://www.tuxation.com/chrooting-into-a-linux-environment.html) page I gained access to the broken Ubuntu installation and executing the following fixed the issue. After that I took out the LiveCD and rebooted and then I could login normally. I finally reinstalled the latest nVidia driver.

`mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia`