# Computer boots up to command line(probably)

Tags: boot, nvidia

I am very new to Ubuntu. I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 2 days before. I was having a good time on Ubuntu till today when I was installing some nvedia drivers. While they weren't installed (in fact not downloaded), i think it would be the reason for my problems. When I boot, everything is normal except instead of desktop, a black screen appears in which i can write something. There is something else written like "Stopping save kernel messages", "Stopping log initial device creation" (They are many). Sorry for being so basic, but i am quite a beginner. Please help me solve this and restore the beautiful and fast Ubuntu to normal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably messed up your graphics by installing the wrong nvidia drivers. Try looking at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/198116/115738

Comment: How did you install the drivers? I can probably help you restore it if I know how you installed them.

Comment: There was some addition drivers section (proprietary drivers). And then it had the list of 4 nvedia drivers. There was an activate button. I activated the first.

Comment: It is not a command line if you are not asked to log in first. Rather your Ubuntu boot up process hangs and, as you said, this might be due to the driver installation (attempt). I have had similar situation with one device and what you could try is type "exit" and press enter. It doesn't fix the problem but you might get your Ubuntu booted so you can uninstall the driver.

Comment: OK. I typed exit and then pressed enter. But nothing happened, the cursor just jumped to the next line.

Comment: OK, I just needed to try that first. Do you have only Ubuntu installed or dual-boot system? Did you use wubi?

Comment: Also edit your question so that you give more details about your hardware. If it's a laptop then general model name might be enough.

Comment: Are you prompted to log in before you get the black screen instead of a desktop?

Comment: No I am not prompted for any Login

Comment: I have an old pc (6-7 years). CompaQ Perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happened because of corruption of Ubuntu system files
while your nvidia drivers' installation.....

So I suggest you to reinstall Ubuntu and search for latest nvidia drivers which are compatible with Ubuntu...

I hope it may help you.

Comment: There might be no need to reinstall. Also as experience tells us latest is not always the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

Find your nvidia card

```
sudo lshw -class display
```

Example:

```
   product: GF110 [GeForce GTX 580] <----------- this is your card
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia     <----------------- driver
   resources: ...
```

Run

```
sudo apt-get remove <driverpackage>
```

on whatever driver you had installed. If you can't find it, **sudo apt-get search** for it

Look online for the proper driver for your card and install that, and reboot. You should be back up and running.